# Multible vertex buffer objects (VBO) in lwjgl

Tags: opengl, vbo, lwjgl

I was able to get VBO's working for a single mesh.
First I set up opengl:

```
//....
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

For each mesh I generate the buffer (two calls to this function per mesh):

```
vertBuffer = GL15.glGenBuffers( BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1)); 
//same idea for faceBuffer
```

I put the mesh data into FloatBuffers and IntBuffers.
Then I have to send these over to opengl:

```
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer)
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVertPositions,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//same idea for faces.
```

Note: All of the above steps only are done once.

Finally there is rendering:

```
//...
int stride = 0; //0 = compact arrays.
int offset = 0; //Each mesh would need a different offset?

GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, stride, offset);
GL12.glDrawRangeElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVerts, 
        numFaces*3, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, offset);
//Using the "buffer versions" of these functions throws  
//"Cannot use Buffers when Array Buffer Object is enabled"
//Whether or not glEnableClientState is called.
```

Any new mesh I add overwrites the old mesh. Putting ALL of my meshes into the same buffer doesn't sound efficient.
How else can I get multiple meshes to coexist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a quite simple issue.

In order to use multiple VBOs, you have to keep the ID assigned by the function glGenBuffers as your reference to the Mesh.

then, when you want to draw that specific mesh, you need to bind it like this (an excerpt of my engine's code):

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Object_To_Draw->PATRIA_Model->MODEL_VBO_ID);

It's like you have 3 meshes, apple, pear and orange, each one has its own ID.

If you want to use the apple, you bind the ID of the apple (in simple words you say to the GPU, take the geometry data from the memory storing the apple.... :)), if you want the pear you point that and oso on.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

> Putting ALL of my meshes into the same buffer doesn't sound efficient.

Actually it is: Switching VBOs is more expensive, than setting some offset. Especially for a lot of small (in terms of number of vertices) objects, putting them into one VBO is recommended.

Anyway: You can use as many VBOs as you like. *glGenBuffers* gives you an ID, which allows you to identify those buffers and target them with *glBindBuffer*.

Comment: But if I put my whole world into the VBO and it far exceeds GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 33000, won't there be problems?

Comment: @KevinKostlan: This is only a recommendation and only applies to the size of the element index array passed to glDrawElements. And you don't have to draw the whole thing at once. Also you can use nonzero offsets into VBOs and use multiple draw calls.